# The following ODE have meaning? $y'(x)=y(x+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wandering diferent tipes of ODE and stumble in to this case, I can't came up with a solution. I wanna know if this have any meaning because the evaluation have an offset.

$$\frac{d}{dx}y(x)=y(x+1)$$

Comment: yes. This is a functional differential equation. They are relatively well studied and have fascinating behavior. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation

Comment: This is a special kind of functional differential equation, known as a "delay differential equation".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation  Well, strictly speaking, to make it "delay" you probably need to change variables from $x$ to $-x$.